# Printing a word in the middle of a line in Java

Tags: java, console

I printed an equilateral triangle and in the middle of a certain row I want to print a word (taken as input). My code is as follows:

```
for (int rows=1; rows <= getHeight(); rows++)
    {
        char charToPrint = '*';
        if(rows == getRowNum()){
            for(int i=0;i<getTextLabel().length();i++){
                 charToPrint = getTextLabel().charAt(i);
            }
        }
        for (int spaces=1; spaces <= number_of_stars; spaces++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int star=1; star <= rows; star++)
        {
            System.out.print(charToPrint);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        number_of_stars = number_of_stars - 1;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
          * 
         * * 
        * * * 
       * * * * 
      * * * * * 
     * * * * * * 
    A A A A A A A 
   * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * *
```

but I wanted the output to be like this:

```
          * 
         * * 
        * * * 
       * * * * 
      * * * * * 
     * * * * * * 
    * L R E Z A * 
   * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Will the length of word be equal to rownumber in which we want to print?

Comment: @akhil_mittal equal or less than it

Comment: input word will have spaces like `L R E Z A` or not like `LREZA`?

Comment: @akhil_mittal it is like "LREZA"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the folllowing code as it seems to work for input `LREZA`:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int userRowNumber = 15;
    int height = 20;
    int number_of_stars = height;
    String charToPrint;
    String inputWord = "LREZA";
    int inputSize = inputWord.length();
    if(userRowNumber < (inputSize*2) ) {
        System.out.println("Not enough space in row to display input text");
        return;
    }
    for (int rows=1; rows <= height; rows++)
    {
        charToPrint = "*";
        if(rows == userRowNumber)
        {
            int startWordFrom = (userRowNumber - inputWord.length())/2;
            printSpace(number_of_stars);
            for (int spaces=0; spaces <rows; spaces++)
            {
                if(spaces >= startWordFrom && spaces <(inputSize*2) ) {
                    System.out.print(inputWord.charAt(spaces-startWordFrom));
                    System.out.print(" ");

                } else {
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
            number_of_stars--;
            rows++;
        }
        printSpace(number_of_stars);
        printCharacter(charToPrint,rows);
        System.out.println("");
        number_of_stars = number_of_stars - 1;
     }
   }
    public static void printSpace(int number_of_stars) {
        for (int spaces=1; spaces <= number_of_stars; spaces++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    public static void printCharacter(String charToPrint, int numberOfTimes) {
        for (int star=1; star <= numberOfTimes; star++)
        {
            System.out.print(charToPrint);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
```

There are certain points to observe while handling the input string. We need to try to centralize the input and also need to put a space after every alphabet of input. The output I got out of this program is:

```
                    * 
                   * * 
                  * * * 
                 * * * * 
                * * * * * 
               * * * * * * 
              * * * * * * * 
             * * * * * * * * 
            * * * * * * * * * 
           * * * * * * * * * * 
          * * * * * * * * * * * 
         * * * * * * * * * * * * 
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * L R E Z A * * * * * 
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

which is I assume expected.

Comment: but it doesnt work for height=10 and inputRow = 7 .. it gives me outOfRange exception

Comment: Actually for input of size n the space required is 2n (n for input and n for space) and I have added this condition at top itself. Also you may need to make some changes here and there as per requirement but this code will give you the idea how to handle this problem.